# Counting the number of copy and move of a std::vector

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I have a program written in C++11 and I would like to count the number of move and copy (construction and assignment) of `std::vector<double>` objects. Is there a way to do that?

Best regards

Comment: Hard to do that on a `double` (or a `vector<double>`) without wrapping it and wreaking havoc on the code that expects a plain old `double`.

Comment: For what it's worth I think your question is a rather interesting one.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Why the attempt to close for "unclear what your are asking"? I find it pretty clear.

Comment: Not really unless you modify the `std::vector` code and add a static counter for the move ctor and copy ctor. Of course don't do this on a production environment as modifying the code in `std` (except for full template specializations) is UB (undefined behaviour).

Comment: Why do you want to know that? You may use reason to count these operations yourself directly from the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. The implementation of `std::vector<>` provides no way for that. Neither does any compiler I know of.

As mentioned in the comments, you could create your own counting replacement and use that instead. I.e.

```
struct counting_vector_double
: std::vector<double>
{
  static size_t count_copy_ctor;
  static size_t count_move_ctor;

  counting_vector_double(counting_vector_double const&other)
  : std::vector<double>(other)
  { count_copy_ctor++; }

  // etc
};

// in .cc file:
size_t counting_vector_double::count_copy_ctor = 0;
size_t counting_vector_double::count_move_ctor = 0;
```

(in a multi-threaded situation use `atomic` counters.) To implement this, you may use a `typedef` or `using` directive, like

```
#ifdef CountingMoveCopy
using vector_double = counting_vector_double;
#else
using vector_double = std::vector<double>;
#endif
```

and use `vector_double` in your code.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the best solution so far. Unfortunately, it needs to change the type of std::vector.

Comment: Well, but not your code if you use a generic replacement type.

Answer (score 2):

This answer consider that the OP needs to count the how many times the items of the vector are copied, moved, constructed.. etc) not the vector itself.

---

Although it is not a direct answer to your question, you may be interested in this answer.

Make a small wrapper class around double:

```
struct double_wrapper{
    double_wrapper()=delete;
    double_wrapper(const double value):value_(value){
        ++constructions_count;
    }
    double_wrapper(const double_wrapper& other){
        value_=other.value_;
        ++copies_count;
    }
    double_wrapper(double_wrapper&& other){
        value_=other.value_;
        //invalidate it in someway.. maybe set it to 0 (not important anyway)
        ++moves_count;
    }
    operator double() const {
         return value_;
    }

    double value_;
    static unsigned int copies_count;
    static unsigned int constructions_count;
    static unsigned int moves_count;
}

// in .cpp
unsigned int double_wrapper::copies_count=0;
unsigned int double_wrapper::constructions_count=0;
unsigned int double_wrapper::moves_count=0;
```

Finally, you have to edit the `vector` type (you may short it to Debug Mode with some `#ifdef`):

```
std::vector<double_wrapper> v1;
```

Note: not tested.

Comment: The question regarded the copy and move of `vector<double>`, not of `double` which is always copied, never moved.

Comment: @Walter " `std::vector<double>` objects".. I thought the OP needs to count the operation on its objects. Why do you think it is just for the vector?

Comment: Operations can only be done on objects. Here, the objects in questions are of the type `std::vector<double>`. This is obvious also from the fact that only for the vector the move vs copy is a sensible distinction.

Comment: @Walter I agree with you and probably you are right.. But I do not why I think that the OP miss expressed themself.. anyway thanks for clarification

Comment: @Human As Walter said, it was for `std::vector<double>`, not for `double`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to circumvent the restriction could be by making a class Vector inheriting an std::vector and then overload the move and copy operators to increment internal counters.